# What is the word for something that has been covered in a lot of sources?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase that describes when a topic has been subject to a preponderance of in-depth coverage, similar to "well-trodden" but more fitting. I'd like to avoid any kind of moralizing language like "trite" or "notable/important" in terms of *how* it's been covered—at most, it would be acceptable to say that the subject has been *adequately* covered—but I'd like the connotation to be just that it *has* been covered in a lot of sources.

Sample sentences:

> We can say that issue of the tampon tax is [well-covered] now that
> dozens of journalists have written about it.
>
> I can write her biography now that her life has been [well-covered in sources].

Comment: I can't help you with a single word, but the phrase "put to bed" is often used in this context: "the issue of the Tampon Tax has been put to bed..."

Comment: Not very different from your definition: "extensively covered" may fit.

Comment: Isn't something covered in lots of source an *enchilada*?

Comment: Maybe _all-around_, _widespread_,  and I'd cautiously recommend  _far-heard_ as in _a far-heard story_ [?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***[Well-documented](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/well-documented)*** may fit in the context:

> - based on or supported with a lot of written evidence.

MacMillan Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

More colloquially, it's been "done to death". According to the [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+done+to+death):

> if a particular style or subject is done to death, it is used or discussed so many times that it is not interesting any more

Answer (score 1):

To place the emphasis on the notion that the matter has been discussed in great depth and breadth, you could use the following phrase:

discussed/covered ***extensively***

[extensive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extensive) (Merriam Webster)

> *having wide or considerable extent*

[extensive](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/extensive) (Cambridge Dictionary)

> covering a large area; having a great range

Answer (score 0):

In scholarly articles, you would say the topic has been

***well studied***

In a more journalistic context, we say that it's been

***well covered***

I don't know how to document this.  You could satisfy yourself that these two expressions are used the way you have in mind by googling with quotes, for example "has been well covered".

Here are your two example sentences:

> The issue of the tampon tax has been well covered by the press.
>
> I can write her biography now that her life has been well covered by various sources.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Cambridge Idioms, I would say for a subject well covered, “It’s been beat to death”; comprehensively; extensively.